# Why are quantum vortices so large?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, vortex, superfluidity

Quantum vortices in helium are almost macroscopic, and can be be imaged in a light microscope:

http://www.aps.org/units/dfd/pressroom/papers/gaff09.cfm

How can vorticity be quantized on *such a large scale*. The angular momentum in the fluid around a quantum vortex is many, many orders of magnitude more than Planck's constant.

Comment: Nothing in that article suggests that it is *easy* to image the vortices. I think the group's method of capturing the vortices on film is pretty clever.